# UI not updating added item when using SetProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, list, prism, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ListBox on my MainWindow with the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMExample"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="241" Margin="24,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I have my MainWindowViewModel

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMExample
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; set; }

        private List<string> items;

        public List<string> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { SetProperty(ref items, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Items = new List<string>();
            Items.Add("Item 1");
            AddItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddItem);
        }

        private void ExecuteAddItem()
        {
            Items.Add("Item 2");
        }
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that the SetProperty method raised the INotifyPropertyChanged event whenever the property was changed.

Whenever I run this program I can see that the ListBox on the MainWindow does have the item "Item 1" however when I press the Add Item button the item "Item 2" does not get added to the UI although it does get added to the Items list.

I know if I use ObservableCollection instead of List I can get the "Item 2" to be added to the ListBox.  But why using List does this not work if I am using the SetProperty method?

Am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Don't use List in a viewmodel if items will be added to the list. Use ObservableCollection. Why would you expect `Items.Add("Item 2");` to call the *setter* for `Items` after you add the item? Nothing there calls the Items setter at all.

Comment: My misunderstanding I had thought that adding an item to the list called the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only notification you raise for `Items` is in the setter when you assign a new List to the property. This code does not assign a new `List<string>` instance to `Items`. It calls the getter for `Items` and adds a string to the list. No notification events are raised, because you never execute any code that raises a notification event.

```
Items.Add("Item 2");
```

Here's your `get` block:

```
get { return items; }
```

It doesn't raise any events. It's called before `List<String>.Add()`, in any case. How could it know that the next thing you're planning to do is add an item to the list? Maybe you'll just be enumerating it. And if it did know, what use would it be to raise the event *before* you add the item?

`List<String>.Add()` doesn't raise any events either.

Use `ObservableCollection<String>` if you want the UI to be notified when you add items to the collection. That's why `ObservableCollection<T>` exists: So there's a collection that notifies the UI when you add or remove items. If there mere vague proximity of code that raises events were sufficient, `ObservableCollection<T>` wouldn't be needed. But there it is.